# Custom select options html attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an "add new product page" and I have a field in the database table "jos_stockmovement", "`start_week`" which contains data for the year and week.

In my "Add New Product" page I have a field dropdown-list named "Start Week" which holds the year and week, for example, "2012/36".

I want to make it so past weeks can be viewed but only the current week can be selected.

Here's my code:

```
<td colspan="99">
  <%= fld.select :start_week, options_for_select(
    StockMovement.order("year DESC, week DESC").map { | val |
      [ "#{ val.year }/#{ val.week }", val.id ]
      },
      :selected => @product.start_week
    ),
    :class => "ddl_SW"
  %>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to add the disabled attribute to the past week options, like

```
<select name="post[stock_movement]">
  <option value="1">Present</option>
  <option value="2" disabled="disabled">Past</option>
  <option value="3" disabled="disabled">Past</option>
</select>
```

You can do this in Rails3 (I don't think you can in Rails2) by using [options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) as you were trying to.

**stock_movement.rb**

```
# not sure about the scope, maybe need to put in a lambda ?
scope :option_tags, order("year DESC, week DESC").map(&:option_tag)

def before_now?
  # your test to know if the thing is before today or not
end

def option_tag
  ["#{ stock_movement.year }/#{ stock_movement.week }",
   val.id,
   before_now? ? {:disabled => :disabled} : {}]
end
```

**your_view.rb**

```
<td colspan="99">
  <%= fld.select :start_week,
                 options_for_select(StockMovement.option_tags,
                                    :selected => @product.start_week),
                 :class => "ddl_SW" -%>
</td>
```

How about that? I could not test it but should be ok.